# Call same DID and CID ins asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I have tried to make calls from my same Outbound Route number to my Inbount Route.
I have Inbound Route >> IVR >> extensions.

When I call from my outbound route to Inbound Route (same number, example: 955555441 IN and OUT 955555441) it does not work, I answer the call but the IVR does not come out. The call recording is made but nothing happens.

thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Some providers not support SIP loop. There is some logic which eleminate loops, which do reinvite. Some switches can't send rtp to own ip.

Solution is create custom trunk type custom to Local/$NUMBER$@from-pstn/n and create outbound route just with your DID to that trunk. It will go your inbound context without hitting provider.